# pylint: getting it to understand decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators, pylint

pylint doesn't seem to take into account decorators.

I have a decorator such that

```
@decorator
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    pass
```

becomes

```
def foo(arg2):
    pass
```

but pylint keeps complaining that when I call foo I'm missing an argument. I'd rather not disable this warning as it's quite useful even for those decorated functions. Is there a way to **just make it understand, man**?

Comment: But wouldn't then the warning go away? If it understood i mean. Assuming that it doesn't that is.

Comment: You mean that code that uses `foo('one argument')` is flagged as invalid because the decorator passes in the extra argument?

Comment: If I write ```foo('bar')``` it interprets ```'bar'``` as ```arg1``` and complains ```missing argument arg2```.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/259

While it remains unfixed, other than disabling the check with `# pylint: disable=missing-kwoa`, your only option is to workaround by:

1. Not using `@decorator` syntax, as polku suggests; or
2. Not having decorators change the function signature; or
3. Providing a default value, even if it's never used or raises an exception.

Or, 4. Contribute a fix to the pylint project!

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like that

```
def decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(1, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def z(a, b):
    return a + b

print( z(5) )
```

A simple solution that don't ask for too much change in your code is to just forget the @, that is just syntactic sugar. It works for me.

```
def z(a, b):
    return a + b
z = decorator(z)

print( z(5) )
```

Comment: that is nice and also solves mocking with autospec. shame about the ugly syntax.